# Where can I find ServerResponse object's properties in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Recently I am following the book Node.js In Action,
In chapter 9 there is a message module, and the following is a function in this module,
I am very confused about what 'this' object is when the res.message is get called,
so I print out 'this' object's name

```
//in lib/messages.js
```

`var express = require('express');
 var res = express.response;
 console.log(res.constructor.name); //ServerResponse`

```
res.message = function (msg, type){
  var sess = this.req.session;  //what will be the this object?
  console.log(this.constructor.name); //ServerResponse
  console.log(this.req.constructor.name); //IncomingMessage 

  ...
}
```

When the message module is called in app.js, 
It seems that 'this' is a ServerResponse object, but I checked node.js manual, I can't find that the ServerResponse object has its own 'req' property, so it must be its prototype's property then.

My question is, how do I know 'ServerResponse' has a 'req' property so I can use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express takes the `ServerResponse` and adds extra data, which is where the `.req` attribute comes from.  If, in general, you want to check if an object has an attribute in node.js, you can just do:

```
if (obj.attribute !== undefined) { ... do stuff ... }
```

Comment: Thank you! Would you mind provide more info on where ServerResponse object adds the req attribute? I checked express.js repo's lib/response.js, I can't fine the code to add the req attribute.  link https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/response.js